# ImportError: No module named pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

and I installed python-matplotlib using apt-get command.

When using this code in python command-line,

```
#!/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

# test.py

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

this works.

but when using .py file, this error appears.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/cloud/Dropbox/dc/hw02/matplotlib.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyplot
```

Please help..

Comment: did you tried  :pip freeze

Comment: @csharpcoder yes I just did. but still same..

Comment: I mean does it lists the module pyplot in the installed list

Comment: Can you show the output of `which python`

Comment: @csharpcoder yes.. version is 1.3.1

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta /usr/bin/python

Comment: OK. I solved problem. In project folder, there was matplotlib.pyc. Everything works now after delete matplotlib.pyc. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As evident from the traceback, you have named your file `matplotlib.py`. Thus, python is trying to do a `local` import. Rename your file to something other than `matplotlib.py`.